# Factorial calculation in python

Tags: python, stack, factorial

```
def factorial_stack(n):
    stack = []
    while n > 0:
        stack.append(n)
        n -=1
    result = 1
    while stack is not None:
        result *= stack.pop()
        
    return result
```

The above code ends in an error - `IndexError: pop from empty list`.
However, the below code runs fine.

```
def factorial_stack2(n):
    stack = []
    while n > 0:
        stack.append(n)
        n -= 1
    result = 1
    #while stack is not None:
    while len(stack) >0:
        result *= stack.pop()

    return result
```

The only difference is in how I check if the stack is empty. From my understanding  `stack is not None` and `len(stack) >0` are checking the same condition. Then why the first case results in an error?

Comment: Your understanding is wrong, size 0 and `None` are very different things. You can however cover for both in one check using `while stack:`

Comment: There are many things in Python that are treated as False:  the word False, the word None, the integer 0, a floating 0.0, an empty list [], an empty tuple (), and an empty dict {}. Even though they all evaluate "false", they are not the same.

Comment: `is` checks for identity.  "Is stack the one and only `None` singleton object?".  No, it is a `list`, so `stack is not None` is always true.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

None is like Null in Databases we don't know what it is.
I recommend that you read the definition
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_none.asp
especially this passage

```
The None keyword is used to define a null value, or no value at all.

None is not the same as 0, False, or an empty string. None is a data type of its own (NoneType) and only None can be None.
```

Summary this fragment

```
while stack is not None:
        result *= stack.pop()
```

Clears the list so this is reasons of your errors.